# Hover text of canvas in other div

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to put text beside the canvas doughnut. This text is based on the hover information of each slide, but instead of appear on the top pf the image i want it to be next to it. (2 images as example)

https://jsfiddle.net/jak2e4zr/

**HTML**

```
    <canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

---

**JS**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var data = {
    labels: ['Residential', 'Non-Residential', 'Utility'],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [19, 26, 55],
            weight: 2,
            spacing : 5,
            borderWidth : 0,
            backgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                "#FFCE56"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                "#FFCE56"
            ]
        }]
};


var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: {
        circumference: 180,
        rotation: -180,
        
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                displayColors: false,
                titleAlign: 'center',
                xAling: 'center'                    
            }
        },
        hoverOffset: 15,
    }
}); `
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdEvK.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isCJr.png)

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

The chart.js tooltip object accepts an additional property called `position` which, well, affects the position of the tooltip. By default it only accepts two strings for setting the mode being either `"average"` or `"nearest"`. Luckily you're able to define your own mode by extending the `Chart.Tooltip.positioners` object.

As you want your tooltip to be somewhere in the middle, we can make something like this:

```
Chart.Tooltip.positioners.middle = function(elements, eventPosition) {

    const chart = this._chart;
        return {
            x: chart.chartArea.width/2,
            y: chart.chartArea.height/2
        };
    }
```

...so simply querying the chart's current dimensions and take the half of it. This mode can then be used by it's name `"middle"`.

Here's a complete example:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
Chart.Tooltip.positioners.middle = function(elements, eventPosition) {
  const chart = this._chart;
  return {
    x: chart.chartArea.width / 2,
    y: chart.chartArea.height / 2
  };
}
var data = {
  labels: ['Residential', 'Non-Residential', 'Utility'],
  datasets: [{
    data: [19, 26, 55],
    weight: 2,
    spacing: 5,
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#36A2EB",
      "#FFCE56"
    ]
  }]
};


var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    circumference: 180,
    rotation: -180,

    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        position: 'middle',
        backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
        titleColor: '#000000',
        displayColors: false,
        titleAlign: 'center',
        xAlign: 'left'
      }
    },

    hoverOffset: 15,
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```